# sbs 2008 firewall, allowing only 3 IP numbers to connect to port 25, block all others

Tags: firewall, windows-sbs-2008

I need to allow only 3 IP's to communicate inbound with port 25 on my SBS. I set up two rules (one for TCP and one for UDP) where the rule says "Allow the connection" and in Scope under "Remote IP Adress" I put the three IP's I want allowed.

But I can still telnet into my email server from a computer not on the list of allowed IP's.

I listed the rules by port number and there is no other rule active that affects port 25.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong here?` - Not providing enough detail in your question. Do you mean that you only want to allow these three ip addresses to communicate with a specific port and block all other communication from all other ip address to all other ports? `I need to allow only 3 IP's to communicate inbound with my SBS` is way too broad and vague of a statement to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You got most of it correct, but I want to do this only for port 25, that is block all communication to port 25 except traffic from these 3 IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was confusing me is that I had created a firewall filter that allowed only 3 IP addresses to port 25. But I am fairly new to Windows networking so I didn't know how the firewall filters were read, that is in what order they were read. Apparently windows first reads the filters that block and then reads the filters that allow traffic.

I also noticed that I had a lot of filters in my firewall that allowed all traffic through all ports, this is default filters that get set up by SBS when a certain role is installed. So I decided to edit all those filter and limit the scope of them to local subnet in Remote Address and lo and behold, I had all of a sudden closed port 25 to all outside traffic.

Then enabling those filters I created to allow my 3 IP addresses, got my mail flowing correctly.

Very strange behavior of SBS to create such filters that allow all traffic.